# Vagrant --no-destroy-on-error option not working in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, winrm

I'm having trouble decrypting the password to an AWS instance. After running "vagrant up" and seeing the AWS instance running, Vagrant gives me the following output:

```
==> default: Waiting for instance to become "ready"...
==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> default: Decrypting WinRM password from AWS...
==> default: Terminating the instance...
```

However, I don't want Vagrant to terminate the instance. The instance has to be running for me to debug the decryption problem. I came across the option --no-destroy-on-error, but the instance is still terminated when I run "vagrant up --no-destroy-on-error"

How can I tell Vagrant "don't terminate the instance you've started"?

Comment: Did you check https://serverfault.com/questions/738480/why-does-this-aws-instance-provisioned-by-vagrant-terminate-as-soon-as-it-comes

Comment: I've seen that error before, but I don't see it here. In any case, even if I did see it, shouldn't the --no-destroy-on-error prevent instance termination?